# DNS Resolution on Linux (parallel/asynchronous vs serial/synchronous)

Tags: linux, networking, dns

I've noticed that Linux seems to have serial/synchronous DNS resolution rather than parallel/asynchronous DNS resolution by default.

I did my testing inside Virtualbox with 2 network adapters (`eth0`, `eth1`), one for NAT and the other is a bridged network to my home router which is connected to the public internet. This gave me 2 DNS servers, one from the VirtualBox NAT, and the other which is my home network router's DNS.

This was the contents of my `/etc/resolv.conf`:

```
vagrant@vagrant-ubuntu-trusty-64:~$ cat /etc/resolv.conf
# Dynamic resolv.conf(5) file for glibc resolver(3) generated by resolvconf(8)
#     DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE BY HAND -- YOUR CHANGES WILL BE OVERWRITTEN
nameserver 10.0.2.3
nameserver 10.1.1.1
```

Then I tried contacting google twice on my root namespace using `eth0`, and twice in my network namespace that used the bridge `eth1`:

```
vagrant@vagrant-ubuntu-trusty-64:~$ curl -w "@timing_curl" -o /dev/null -s http://google.com

            time_namelookup:  0.004
               time_connect:  0.030
            time_appconnect:  0.000
           time_pretransfer:  0.031
              time_redirect:  0.000
         time_starttransfer:  0.066
                            ----------
                 time_total:  0.067

vagrant@vagrant-ubuntu-trusty-64:~$ curl -w "@timing_curl" -o /dev/null -s http://google.com

            time_namelookup:  0.004
               time_connect:  0.032
            time_appconnect:  0.000
           time_pretransfer:  0.032
              time_redirect:  0.000
         time_starttransfer:  0.065
                            ----------
                 time_total:  0.065

vagrant@vagrant-ubuntu-trusty-64:~$ sudo ip netns exec robots curl -w "@timing_curl" -o /dev/null -s http://google.com

            time_namelookup:  10.530
               time_connect:  10.560
            time_appconnect:  0.000
           time_pretransfer:  10.560
              time_redirect:  0.000
         time_starttransfer:  10.594
                            ----------
                 time_total:  10.594

vagrant@vagrant-ubuntu-trusty-64:~$ sudo ip netns exec robots curl -w "@timing_curl" -o /dev/null -s http://google.com

            time_namelookup:  5.519
               time_connect:  5.548
            time_appconnect:  0.000
           time_pretransfer:  5.548
              time_redirect:  0.000
         time_starttransfer:  5.582
                            ----------
                 time_total:  5.583
```

As you can see there's a significant difference in `time_namelookup` between root namespace using `eth0` and robots namespace using `eth1`.

I swapped the 2 nameserver entries around in `/etc/resolv.conf`, and this reduced the name look up time inside the robots namespace. I also tried with ping, which resulted in the same time difference.

This all leads me to conclude that DNS resolution inside Linux by default is sequential. Is there a reason for this? Why not resolve DNS in parallel? And would the right solution be to run a local recursive DNS server that is capable of parallel resolution?

(BTW, this is the format used for curl https://gist.githubusercontent.com/spiermar/8888552/raw/efc0b09699b0fd619eb32638d4f1099db528fe54/curl-format)

Comment: look at the nameserver directive in `resolv.conf(5)`.  It explains the order used and how to specify serial or paralell.

Comment: I looked at it, nothing jumped out about using the nameservers in parallel.

Comment: yes, I know.... it says about doing all the nameservers configured in one nameserver directive serially.  I have read that BSD implementation allows you to configure parallel search by using several nameserver directives (serial: all in one directive; paralell: one server per directive) but, as the linux page doesn't say anything about that, perhaps your guess is correct.  If my comment would be a complete response I should have written a complete answer, not this comment.

Comment: I have just read again the BSD pages (on an openBSD 5.7 box) and nothing appears also for parallel searches, so I'm afraid you have to cope with serial searches.  I read about this a long time ago.  Paralell searches normally are reserved to nameservers, that work iteratively and not recursively.

Comment: for paralell searches, perhaps you can use the `resolver(3)` family of functions and do it yourself.